# Is there a convenient way to detect unittests that are causing external calls?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have all of these tests in Django for code uses various third party APIs which I'm of course mocking, but some of the code is old and sometimes people make mistakes. I'd like the code to yell loudly when it makes an external call if possible, so that I can figure out which of the 100s of dots that mark passing tests is slowing the tests down by not having the right things mocked.

Is there a convenient way of making sure none of my code is relying on things outside of my computer? My most naive idea is to simply disconnect from the network and see what errors I get, but that's hardly a smart long term solution.

Comment: If the code is old, I would go with the disconnect from network solution, do the fixes, and then tell people what NOT to do in the future. It's probably the fastest way to go about it. I would advise not to try and anticipate a lot of things before they happen. They will only complicate your job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about detecting external calls, but what you can do, is timing test execution times and then checking the slower tests.

You could use [nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/) + the [pinnocchio](http://darcs.idyll.org/~t/projects/pinocchio/doc/#stopwatch-selecting-tests-based-on-execution-time) plugin, to time your tests.

This also seems interesting: http://blog.mahmoudimus.com/2011/02/developing-a-nose-test-plugin-to-time-python-tests/